# How can I start Tortoise-ORM in a celery docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, celery, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I have an application in which I use a postgresql and celery database. Each element is running in a different container, in the celery container I am already connected to the postgres database, however I don't know how I could configure tortoise-orm to start in the celery container, since I have a task in which I want to interact with the database using tortoise.

This is my docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: fastapi_celery_example_web
    # '/start' is the shell script used to run the service
    command: /start
    # this volume is used to map the files and folders on the host to the container
    # so if we change code on the host, code in the docker container will also be changed
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8010:8000
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=fastapi_celery
      - POSTGRES_USER=fastapi_celery
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=fastapi_celery

  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: fastapi_celery_example_celery_worker
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  # Additional dependencies
  && apt-get install -y telnet netcat \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY ./compose/local/fastapi/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/fastapi/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/fastapi/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/fastapi/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/fastapi/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

The task:

```
@shared_task()
def task_send_welcome_email(user_pk):
    from project.users.models import User

    user = User.filter(id=user_pk).first()
    logger.info(f'send email to {user.email} {user.id}')
```

Comment: Please share some docker and docker-compose files

Comment: I have updated the question with docker compose and dockerfile. In addition to the task in which I want to use tortoise. thanks